# What's wrong or missing with my HTML and JS palindrome script?

Tags: palindrome

function isPalindrome (userEntry) {
               str = str.toLowerCase;
               str = str.replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
               str = (i = 0 || i Your word is not a palindrome";
                   }
               }
                  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "

Your word is a palindrome

";
           }

```
        <h2>Palindrome detection</h2>
        <code>Detect if a string is a palindrome</code><br /><br />

        Enter a word with 10 or less characters <input type="text" id="userEntry"><br />
        <button type="button" onclick="isPalindrome();">Enter</button><br /><br />
```

```
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change some code in isPalindrome and add div to give result.

```js
function isPalindrome (userEntry) { 
var re = /[\W_]/g;
  var lowRegStr = userEntry.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
  var reverseStr = lowRegStr.split('').reverse().join(''); 
  if( reverseStr === lowRegStr){
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your word is a palindrome"; 
  }
  }
```

```html
 <h2>Palindrome detection</h2>
        <code>Detect if a string is a palindrome</code><br /><br />

        Enter a word with 10 or less characters <input type="text" id="userEntry"><br />
        <button type="button" onclick="isPalindrome(document.getElementById('userEntry').value)">Enter</button><br /><br />
   <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the script.  My goal is to avoid using the reverse () method.